# Do octopuses have better eyes than humans?

Tags: zoology, vision, eyes, invertebrates

I've [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_eye) that unlike humans, octopuses have eyes "designed" the "right way", i.e. with the nerve fibers behind the retina, thus getting rid of the blind spot we humans have as well as theoretically improving eyesight.

Have there been tests to compare octopus sight with that of humans, and do they indeed have better vision than us?

Comment: I'd suggest adding the tag "cephalopods".

Comment: Why would removing the blind spot result in better vision?

Comment: the blind spot perhaps not, (although it could come in ahndy if the eyes are on the side of your head and not in front), but mostly one would think that the lack of nerve fibers would somehow improve resolution, vision in dim light, etc.

Comment: But octopus do not have fovea - so no more keen vision! They may have more photoreceptors , but they have no more complex brains than humans - the brain behind the eye is more important than eye itself.

Comment: monkey eyes can move so fast as to examine 10 branches and stems every second while they jump through the trees with awesome focus and positional mapping. chimps eyes have positional mapping for tree climbing that is 10x faster than human eye movement, so eyes have specializations for fine movement, distance, speed, narrow, wide, all very refined. eyes and ears are extremely advanced and perfected for the given environment. animal's primary senses are normally very near to perfection for their actions and needs. probably octopi trade range of eye movement for a more fixed structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of advantages and disadvantages of possessing the eyes of octopuses.

- The first **advantage** of the octopus eye is that it has no blind spot. This means that octopuses can see everything that is going on in their environment, and are more aware of predators and prey than some vertebrates. Also, they have many more photoreceptors than vertebrates, at roughly **20,000-50,000/mm<sup>2</sup>** which means that their vision is much better than that of any human.
- The **disadvantage** of the octopus eye is that it can not see in colour. The eyes possess no cones, only the invertebrate equivalent of rods. This means that  octopuses can only distinguish between light and dark.

Comment: So if a diver and an octopus where to be threatened by a shark, the octopus would see the shark first?

Comment: Of course it depends, As I cleared above both have some advantages and disadvantages. So, It's completely depends. But In some manner of course the Octopus will see the Shark first because they didn't have blind spot so their field of view is more than a common person.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Do you have a reference for the photoreceptor claim?

Comment: "Like other cephalopods, they can distinguish the polarization of light. Color vision appears to vary from species to species, being present in *O. aegina* but absent in *O. vulgaris*." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Sensation

Comment: Would the blind spot matter? The respective blind spots of the two eyes don't overlap, so unless you are a pirate (I suppose a frequent victim of sharks), you will still *see* all the things in either of your blind spots, there will just be two small spots in your FOV where you don't have depth perception.

Comment: In terms of the number of photoreceptors; that may only benefit light sensitivity and not visual acuity dependent on the connections with the secondary neurons. The blind spot in humans is mitigated by binocular vision.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer above, another advantage of cephalopod eyes is the lower risk of retina detachment. ([HumanEvolution](https://thehumanevolutionblog.com/2015/01/12/the-poor-design-of-the-human-eye/))

Also, cephalopod eye focus image by moving the lense (like a camera or telescope), not by changing the lense's curvature, as in vertebrate eye ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_eye)). Hence, I speculate that cephalopod would not experience either [myopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-sightedness) or [hyperopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far-sightedness). Cephalopod may still have problem with [presbyopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presbyopia) at old age, affecting both near and far vision, however.

Furthermore, this article comparing human and cephalopod eyes might be of interest: [QuarkPhysics](http://www.quarkphysics.ca/scripsi/vision-of-octopi-and-the-persistence-of-error/)

Comment: I thought presbyopia would not affect cephalopods. In vertebrates it's due to the lense becoming stiffer with age so it can't change shape, but as you say this is not how cephalopod eyes focus.

Comment: Ah, I mean if the muscles that move the eyes are not working properly when the animal ages, cephalopod would suffer presbyopia as vertebrates do.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point (although I have no idea if old octopusses suffer a similar kind of muscle stiffness as humans, there's probably a lot more here that we don't know!).